# How to set optgroup select label in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a select group in Vue.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/vwjxc5dq/

I've tried this:

```
<optgroup v-for="option in options" v-bind:label="option">
  <option v-for="sub in option" v-bind:value="option.value">
   {{ sub.text }}
  </option>
</optgroup>
```

My data:

```
data: {
  selected: 'A',
  options: {
    First: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' }
    ],
    Second: [
     { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are binding the `label` attribute to `option`, which is an array. What you want is to bind to the object's key.

You can get the key of each option by specifying a second parameter in the `v-for` directive:

```
<optgroup v-for="(option, key) in options" v-bind:label="key">
```

---

I'd also rename your `options` property to `optionGroups` to avoid further confusion:

```
data: {
  selected: 'A',
  optionGroups: {
    First: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' }
    ],
    Second: [
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
}
```

That way, the template will make more sense:

```
<optgroup v-for="(group, name) in optionGroups" :label="name">
  <option v-for="option in group" :value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Vue3 composition api version:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const options = {
  First: [
    { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
    { text: 'Two', value: 'B' }
  ],
  Second: [
    { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
  ]
}

const selected = ref('A');
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <optgroup v-for="(group, groupName) in options" :label="groupName" :key="groupName">
      <option v-for="item in group" :value="item.value" :key="item.value">
        {{ item.text }}
      </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <p>Selected value: <span>{{ selected }}</span></p>
</template>
```

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9U01v2zAM/SuELm6BLD70lrkB2qIDtkM7LLlNO3gOk6qVJUGS0wyB//soKnbdD/QkkXx8JJ+oo7hybr7vUCxEFRqvXISAsXNLaVTrrI9wBI9b6GHrbQsFQQtppGmsCRGsi4oucAlHaQC+KR/iAn6nO1BixAOZxb3BYgb7WndI1lUB/ewNYv1sJ4hrQiTAH4atkGpt3rOuHzxOeW+GLGnoHDoMqLGJuKEWaYwzqn7+VZqqzLPSlGREbJ2uI5IFUOUM2H9p7Qb1pRQDhRQMIAiNvfO2cwTaWk+QMzZnwMdd3eI5KDOoIwUsdP2XuUZAcj7hv9euE3+uQKkjv6IWEyNjUyoPfQrM2XghnPpGRhLuCBxJ8kHPUnGpMtcaZksml8lqlHl6FopMt1wNgp50r4KrzZLIR6X7nrKSsyoTSVWO+oqZiIHeZat288dgDS0d740UjW2d0ujvB8kWeaNSrNbaPv9gX/QdnnaHch6wefrA/xgOySfFT48B/Z5kGGOx9juMOXy7uiMpJkF68E4T+pPgLwxWd6nHDLvuzIbanuC42+/8dZTZrcPtIaIJw1Cp0YTMP0AK+k43n4z+0u7F/ILzaLlF/x+VrjcU)

Answer (score 0):

according to above answer. I improve optgroup tag by adding label in optgroup tag

```
<optgroup v-for="(group, name) in optionGroups" :key="name" :label="`${name}`">
                
 <option v-for="option in group" :key="option.value">
   {{ option.text }}
    </option>
 </optgroup>
```