# Vue.js Whitespaces in HTML select box

Tags: html, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I am new to Vue.js and I am currently trying to figure out how to maintain whitespaces in the options of my HTML "select" drop-down. I am using v-for to populate the list like this:

```
<option
 v-for="category in displayCategories"
 :key="category">
 {{ category }}
</option>
```

And the list items look like this (in a string array):

```
 `SECTOR`,
 `   Food and Drink`,
 `   Education`,
 `   Transport`
```

Currently, something seems to be trimming out the space characters. I'm not sure if the problem lies with Vue or HTML...

Thanks for your time,

Josh

Comment: This is a characteristic of HTML. https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33

Comment: @Bert I've just read the article. Is it possible to force HTML to render whitespaces with a tag? How would I implement this into my Vue code? Thanks, Josh

Comment: You can, but not easily in an `option` tag. What are you trying to do? Some indication that certain options are grouped by a category?

Comment: @Bert Yeah. Objects are grouped into categories which are displayed with indentations of white space.

Comment: You might want to try an approach [like this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812817/how-to-set-optgroup-select-label-in-vue-js).

Comment: @Bert Thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow. I had looked into optgroups but I couldn't see how I would implement it but I think I understand it a bit more now...

Comment: The other option is to use a component like VueSelect. http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

Comment: @Bert I have just implemented the <optlist> approach and it works alright but I can't think how I could have sub-categories within categories. I have modified my list items to look like this:

`SECTOR: [


        { text: 'Food and Drink', value: 1 },


        { text: 'Education', value: 2 },


        { text: 'Society', value: 3 },


        { text: 'Pharmaceutical', value: 4 },


        { text: 'Energy', value: 5 }


      ]

`