# Vue.js and Form array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, knockout.js

I am converting a form from knockout to vue 2 with an ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller for the back end.  This is my first attempt using vue.  When the user presses the + button, it adds a new row onto the form.  The issue I'm having is submitting that to the back end.  The old knockout code dynamically set the name attribute in the form elements to Quantities so the form array properly submits all of the data.  I would like to do the same thing with vue but am having a a bit of trouble dynamically setting the name of each element dynamically.  What would be the best way to do this in order to submit the form without having to rewrite the Controller signature?  It should store the form array under the name Quantities.

Image:

[image: Form screenshot]

HTML:

```
<div id="radios" v-for="(row,key) in order">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        @Html.SmartLabel("systemType", "System Type", true, labelClass)
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" value="@Model.WifiId" v-model="order[key].selectedSystemType" v-on:change="systemChanged(key)"> Wifi
                                        </label>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" value="@Model.WirelessId" v-model="order[key].selectedSystemType" v-on:change="systemChanged(key)"> Wireless
                                        </label>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" value="@Model.FiberId" v-model="order[key].selectedSystemType" v-on:change="systemChanged(key)"> Fiber
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        @Html.SmartLabel("assetType", "Asset Type", true, labelClass)
                                        <!--
                                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812817/how-to-set-optgroup-select-label-in-vue-js
                                        -->
                                        <select id="asset-type" name="" class="form-control" v-model="order[key].selectedAsset" v-on:change="assetTypeChanged(key)">
                                            <optgroup v-for="(group, name) in order[key].assets" v-bind:label="name">
                                                <option v-for="asset in group" v-bind:value="asset">
                                                    {{asset.Name}}
                                                </option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        @Html.SmartLabel("quantity", "Quantity", true, labelClass)
                                        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" v-model="order[key].quantity" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div v-show="costTracked">
                                            @Html.SmartLabel("cost", "Unit Cost", true, labelClass)
                                            <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" v-model="order[key].cost" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span style="cursor:pointer" v-on:click="removeItem(key)">
                                            X
                                        </span>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Vue.js code:

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#vue-app',
            data: {
                assets: {},
                assetQuantityEnabled: false,
                costTracked: false,
                order: []
                //Quantities: []
            },
            methods: {
                // Trigger when system type radio selection changes
                systemChanged: function (key) {
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action( "GetAssetsOfSystem", "RadioOrder" )?systemTypeId=' + this.order[key].selectedSystemType, function (data) {
                        var result = {};
                        // Add assets to category (AssetCategory)
                        for (const asset of data) {
                            (asset.AssetCategoryName in result) ? result[asset.AssetCategoryName].push(asset) : result[asset.AssetCategoryName] = [];
                        }
                        // Sort assets within each category
                        for (const option in result) {
                            result[option].sort((a, b) => {
                                return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
                            });
                        }
                        this.order[key].assets = result;
                        this.costTracked = false;
                        this.assetQuantityEnabled = false;
                    }.bind(this));

                },
                assetTypeChanged: function (key) {
                    this.assetQuantityEnabled = true;
                    this.costTracked = this.hasMacOrSerial(this.order[key].selectedAsset);
                },             
                addItem: function () {                    
                    obj = this.defaultObj();
                    this.order.push(obj);
                },
                convertFormData: function(){
                    var q = [];
                    for(let i=0; i < this.order.length; i++)
                    {                        
                        var obj = {
                            AssetTypeId: this.order[i].selectedAsset.AssetTypeId,
                            AssetTypeIsSerialized: this.hasMacOrSerial(this.order[i].selectedAsset),
                            Quantity: this.order[i].quantity,
                            UnitCost: this.order[i].cost
                        };                         
                        q.push(obj);                        
                    }
                    return q;
                },
                defaultObj: function () {
                    return {
                        asset: '',
                        assets: [], // list items
                        cost: 0,
                        quantity: 1,
                        selectedSystemType: null,
                        selectedAsset: null
                    };
                },
                hasMacOrSerial: function (asset) {
                    return (asset.HasMacAddress || asset.HasSerialNumber) ? true : false;
                },
                removeItem: function (key) {
                    this.order.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Controller method signature:

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(
                [Bind(Include = "VendorId,OrderNumber,RequisitionNumber,Quantities,SerializedAssets,Attempt")] InventoryOrderDto dto)
```

Old HTML using Knockout:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default white-box">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Order Summary</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="radios" data-bind="foreach: QuantitiesDisplay, visible: QuantitiesDisplay().length > 0" style="display: none">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: AssetTypeId, attr: {name: 'Quantities[' + $index() + '].AssetTypeId'}" />
                                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: AssetTypeIsSerialized, attr: {name: 'QuantitiesDisplay[' + $index() + '].AssetTypeIsSerialized'}" />
                                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: UnitCost, attr: {name: 'Quantities[' + $index() + '].UnitCost'}" />
                                <div class="col-md-3" data-bind="text: AssetTypeName" style=" word-break: break-all;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Quantity, attr: {name: 'Quantities[' + $index() + '].Quantity'}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" data-bind="visible:AssetTypeIsSerialized, value: UnitCost, attr: {name: 'Quantities[' + $index() + '].UnitCost'}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Remove" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="emptyOrder" data-bind="visible: QuantitiesDisplay().length == 0">
                            No items are currently selected. Please choose from the adjacent pane.
                        </div>
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible: QuantitiesDisplay().length > 0" style="display: none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found it - need to use v-bind to dynamically set the name.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.SmartLabel("quantity", "Quantity", true, labelClass)
    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" v-model="order[key].quantity" v-bind:name="'Quantities[' + key + '].Quantity' " />
</div>
```

https://medium.com/swlh/building-dynamic-forms-with-django-formsets-and-vue-js-f3c6e2dddd4a